# Group content by dynamic database field

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to group content within a Repeater with a dynamic heading?

For example, I have the following in a database:

- Tuesday - math
- Tuesday - science
- Friday - history
- Friday - art

I want it to be displayed in output on a web page as:

- Tuesday - math, science
- Friday - history, art

I want the items to be grouped by day; however, I do not want to create a new database connection for each day of the week, and I don't want to hard code groups. Is there a way to group content by a database field?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to modify the datasource that you're binding to the repeater.

This should work:

```
//original datasource from database
DataTable table = new DataTable();

//modify the datasource using LINQ
var results = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row.Field<string>("Day") into days
              select new
              {
                  Day = days.Key,
                  Class = String.Join(", ", days.Select(t => t.Field<string>("Class")).ToArray())
              };

//bind the repeater to the modified datasource
Repeater1.DataSource = results;
```

**EDIT**

Here are some tutorials to get you started using LINQ:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746
- http://aktripathi.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/linq-for-beginners/
- http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-4

Comment: I am not familiar with LINQ. I'd definitely check this out, thank you! Is this a code behind type of script? I'm not sure where this code would be stuck at...I'm new to ASP, so I'm still learning the waters. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Definitely code-behind. You would use this to modify the datasource before binding the repeater.

Comment: Okay. I'll look into this more. Thanks :)

Comment: Using LINQ will make your life better than straight up SQL. Being new to ASP.NET, I'd suggest investing your time wisely into tools that will be the backbone to your development. A good [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) is definitely one of those tools.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the resources. So much to learn! haha This is good stuff, thanks.

Comment: @JamesJohnson - Do you type this code by hand, or is there a generator that does this for you? How do you learn this stuff? I don't even know where to start. All the books and resources out there seem to gravitate without the showing of codebehind stuff. Any suggestions about how I can learn this stuff?

Comment: It's mostly by hand, with some help from intellisense. The example above utilizes a fairly new language component called LINQ (Language Integrated Query). It looked like greek to me when I first saw it too, but it looks more difficult than it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the resources! I'm looking forward to learning more of this! I appreciate your help.